# ASP.NET Routing a directory request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, routes, global-asax

I have a client that decided they were going to create flyers with a URL they made up. The URL is www.sillyclient.com/golf

They SHOULD have used www.sillyclient.com/sports/golf-tourny

The correct URL uses Routing to send the request to a sports.aspx page and load the page, via this route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SportsRoute", "sports/{sportname}", "~/sports.aspx", True, _
            New RouteValueDictionary(New With _
                {.sportname = "[-_a-bA-B0-9]{1,}"}) _
                )
```

Now I have to find a way to handle the incorrect route, because the posters are everywhere. I don't know how to grab "www.sillyclient.com/golf" and reroute it to the correct page/format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following above the SportsRoute:

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("IncorrectSportsRoute", "{sportname}", "~/sports.aspx", True, _
        New RouteValueDictionary(New With _
            {.sportname = "[-_a-bA-B0-9]{1,}"}) _
            )
```